# Form labels/fields not being centered vertically

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble vertically centering my labels/fields in my form. I have centered the content horizontally but now would also like to add vertical centering. When I run my code i can see that the fieldset padding is off. The value of the padding on the top is less than the value on the bottom. I figure for the vertical centering to occur they should be equal. Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Contact</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="pageHeader">

        </header>


        <nav class="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
                <img src="NewLogo3.png">
        </nav>

        <div class="contact">
            <h1>Get In Touch</h1>
            <form action="index.php" method="POST" >
            <fieldset class="boxShadow">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" class="boxShadow"/>

                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="boxShadow"/>

                <label>Message:</label>
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?" class="boxShadow"></textarea>

                <input type="submit" value="Send message" />

            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <footer id="pageFooter">
            <p>Thanks for visiting my website</p>
            <span>&copy 2013</span>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>



html, body, h1, h2 , ul, nav, img{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
body{
    background: #777777;
    height: 100%;
}

nav{
    background: #40B3DF;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
nav ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #A8CB17;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A8CB17;
    margin-right: 10px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #004158;
    padding: 10px;  
}
nav img{
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 15px;
}
nav li:hover{
    background: #17649A;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #17649A;
}

p{
    padding-top: 3em; 
    color: #454545;
    text-align: center;
}

h1{
    color: #393939;
    font-size: 3em;
    padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(23, 23, 23, 1);
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

footer{
    border-top: 2px solid #393939;
    background: #40B3DF;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;   
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
}
footer p{
    display:inline-block;   
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 1.5em; 
    color: #004158;
}

footer span{
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    right: -45px;   
}

textarea{
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em;

}
label, input[type=submit]{
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
input, label{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 200px;

}
input[type=submit] {    
    margin-top: 2em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 700; 
}

fieldset {
    height: 550px;
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #676767;
    margin: 0 auto;     
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    /*border: 0;*/

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post code that have nothing to do with your problem. Makes it more difficult to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Are you referring to the gap at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap at the bottom of the form is due to the fact that your fieldset has a height of 550px, but your content does not fill that height.  Remove the height, and adjust margin/padding from there.

As for the padding on the fieldset, browsers add padding to fieldsets by default.  To make your site more consistent across browsers, use a CSS reset, like the [HTML5 reset style sheet](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/).  That essentially overrides all of a browser's default styling.  When using it, apply it above all of your other CSS styles.  As for the padding itself, there are a few ways to manage it.

To adjust a certain side, you can use `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `padding-right`, or `padding-left`.

You can adjust top/bottom, left/right using `padding: 10px 15px;`, which would give you 10px on top and bottom, and 15px on the left and right.

You can also specify top, left/right, and bottom with `padding:10px 15px 5px`.

Margins are set the same way, just replace "padding" with "margin".

Comment: Thanks for that advice. When i am using chromes dev tool I see that the padding on the top is 5.6 px and the padding on the bottom is 10px(fieldset). I know i can manually add top padding but i was trying to accomplish this with something that can do it automatically

Comment: I updated my answer.  Sorry if it's long-winded!  I'd use a CSS-reset to make sure there aren't any default styles being applied by browsers, and then adjust the padding from there.  Let me know if that doesn't cover it, and I'll come back to it.

Comment: I was just coming back to say that it was my reset that messed everything up. You are right. I appreciate that fast and reliable help.